# Unable to clear the Multiselect dropdown and populate values in it dynamically

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I have made two multiselect dropdown using multiselect js plugin. 
2<sup>nd</sup> dropdown gets populated on the option selection of 1<sup>st</sup> dropdown. I have use ajax for this purpose. But on ajax callback, 2<sup>nd</sup> dropdown elements are not getting clear, and new options are not populating.

This is my html code:

```html
<div class="row col-md-6" >
    <select id="multidropdown" multiple="multiple" onchange="ChangedView()">
        @foreach (var item in clients)
        {
            <option value=@item.ToString() class="col-md-5"> @item.ToString() </option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<div class="row col-md-6" id="ProgramsDiv">
    <select id="programIDs" multiple="multiple" onchange="SelectSensorsFromPrograms()">
        @foreach (var item in programs)
        {
            <option value=@item.ToString() class="col-md-5"> @item.ToString() </option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

and this is my JavaScript code:

```js
function ChangedView()
{
    $(".mtable").remove();

    var multiclients = $("#multidropdown option:selected").text();
    var program = $("#programIDs option:selected").text();
    var sensors = $("#sensorIDs option:selected").text();
    var request = $.ajax({

        url: '@Url.Action("GetselectedProgramClient")',
        type: 'POST',
        data:
        {
            "ClientNames": multiclients
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data)
        {
            debugger;
            if (data.length > 0)
            {
                $('#programIDs').html('');
                var options = '';
                console.log(data.length+"\n");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] +" " + '</option>';
                    console.log(options);
                }

                $('#programIDs').append(options);
                $('#programIDs').multiselect('rebuild');
            }
        },

        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log("Error: " + xhr.statusText);
            if (xhr.statusText == 'error') {
                return;
            }
            else if (xhr.statusText == 'OK') {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I dont get any error, its just that the items in the 2nd dropdown retain and are not cleared and new items are not being populated in the dropdown.

Comment: I think the reason it does not populate new items is you are using `data:
                {
                    "ClientNames": multiclients
                },` to send multiclients only. You should use separate ajax call to send selected option from `var program = $("#programIDs option:selected").text();`

Comment: No, the controller requires that argument not programs. @FaizanRabbani

Comment: Can you put logs in `success:` and see the data that you get?

Comment: The data in logs gives the correct data @FaizanRabbani

Comment: Change following: 

`$('#programIDs.multiselect').multiselect('rebuild');
$('#programIDs.multiselect').multiselect('refresh');`